# Imager Ubuntu Core 18 Pi4 (arm64) password is not working

Tags: password

Just tried to install ubuntu server using Imager to flash the SD card for my Pi4.
I'm selecting the "Ubuntu Core 18 Pi3/4" 64bit image, flashing works perfect.

Following [the guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#4-boot-ubuntu-server), I'm trying to SSH login. When entering 'ubuntu' as password, I get this error:

> Permission denied, please try again.

I gave a try at exactly the same thing, using this time the Ubuntu 20.04 image for Pi (3/4).
And there, the 'ubuntu' password works.

So I'm assuming that the password for the Ubuntu Core 18 isn't 'ubuntu' but something else.
Any idea what that is? Or I'm wrong and it's completely something else that's the issue here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned both Ubuntu Core and Ubuntu Server in your question, and those are two different things, so I'm not sure which one you're running.

With Ubuntu **Core**, there is no default account -- you need an online Ubuntu SSO (single sign-on) account to create the first account on an Ubuntu Core installation, and you configure the SSO account on the device as part of the first time setup, following along at the "Press enter to configure" prompt. (For more information see [Ubuntu's instructions on the subject](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi-core)).

If you're talking about Ubuntu **Server**, rather than Ubuntu **Core** (both of these are available as separate choices in the official Raspberry Pi Imager) there is a default `ubuntu` account, and the password is `ubuntu`.

But take note: The password won't work *at first*. Ubuntu Server is designed to set itself up using `cloud-init`, like you would see on a cloud computing node in a service such as Amazon EC2. It's a few minutes after booting before the account is configured and ready to log in with. Even after the console login prompt appears and ssh port becomes available, `cloud-init` is still setting things up in the background, and the `ubuntu` user account isn't ready to use yet.

`cloud-init` outputs logs to the Linux console and `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` as it runs; when it is done it will say so, e.g. from Ubuntu Server 20.04:

```
Cloud-init v. 20.2-45-g5f7825e2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 finished at Mon, 07 Sep 2020 03:42:06 +0000. Datasource DataSourceNoCloud [seed=/dev/mmcblk0p1][dsmode=net].  Up 368.84 seconds
```

At this point everything is ready for you to log in.

The default configuration of the `ubuntu` account will force you to change the password from `ubuntu` when you first log in.