# Ubuntu Server 20.10 Raspberry Pi 4B unable to login using Default Password

Tags: server, raspberrypi, 20.10

I used Rasperry Pi imager, to image Ubuntu Server 20.10 32-bit Rpi (2/3/4/400) for armhf architecture.  I have tried to login using ubuntu/ubuntu and pi/raspberry with no success.  I have tried to image serveral times even using 64-bit version but no success.

This is a fresh install, connected via ethernet cable.

```
 sudo ssh ubuntu@10.42.0.1
ubuntu@10.42.0.1's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
ubuntu@10.42.0.1's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
ubuntu@10.42.0.1's password: 
ubuntu@10.42.0.1: Permission denied (publickey,password).
<prompt> /var/log $ sudo ssh pi@10.42.0.1
pi@10.42.0.1's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@10.42.0.1's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@10.42.0.1's password: 
pi@10.42.0.1: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Thought I would try this forum, before I install Raspberry OS.
I waited per [Imager Ubuntu Core 18 Pi4 (arm64) password is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232452/imager-ubuntu-core-18-pi4-arm64-password-is-not-working) , but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I followed these instructions https://medium.com/vacatronics/how-to-install-ubuntu-server-on-raspberry-pi-19f34e33569d , and I was able to login to Rpi using Ubuntu 20.10.  I was prompted to change ubuntu default password, and was successful in doing so using `sudo ssh ubuntu@<IP Address>`.  I did wait ~10minutes before trying login, so not sure if that did anything.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Hook up a monitor/tv to the Pi.
you will see "press enter to config". Create an account at login.ubuntu.com.

PS if you are lucky your own fav. username is still free. Mine wasn't.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I just read responses was focused on Ubuntu Server 20.10 w/Raspberry Pi setup. But I was able to install Ubuntu Server 20.10 64-bit (headless).  Unfortunately, I don't recall that exact steps that specifically resolved issue.  Trying to recollect, here are some steps I did try so others may follow:

1. I hooked up the pi to a Smart TV to act as monitor to see boot messages

   - saw it was hanging on cloud-init
2. Followed instructions found on internet to disable cloud-init.  I am not sure which URL I used but you can search this site, or use https://www.networkreverse.com/2020/06/how-to-remove-cloud-init-from-ubuntu.html#method1 .

- Touching file to disable cloud-init seems to be easiest
- After I imaged SD card, I did update  'user-data' file, and 'network-config' files while I was in 'system-boot' partition, I also 'touched' 'ssh' file in what would be /boot directory

3. I also updated the 'user-data' file to include a username I created, not necessarily to resolve the login issue but more as a "backup".
4. I re-booted and watched output, when I got login prompt I logged in with 'ubuntu' and was prompted to change password which I did sucessfully.

Now all this was to get me into raspberry pi.  After this I:

1. Configured to boot off of 2 SSD drives, trial an error process for me, eventual flashed Ubuntu 20.10 and Rpi image onto both SSD drives, configured to boot off of one drive.
2. Setup SSDs in a RAID1 one configration for data directories.
3. Once I got to this point installed Nextcloud using this guide https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nextcloud-ubuntu-20-04-apache-lamp-stack

*Note:* I did read this URL posted below, and I do believe it prompted me to make some of the changes to boot: I followed these instructions https://medium.com/vacatronics/how-to-install-ubuntu-server-on-raspberry-pi-19f34e33569d

I did initially buy a PoE hat, but I also ended up buying a powered USB Hub for SSD drives as I was getting Low Voltage warnings and hanging which made initial troubleshooting difficult and frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

### Headless set-up (updated in April 2022)

In April 2022 the procedure has changed and **the default username (pi) and password (raspberry) do *not* work anymore**, as announced in the a [blog post on raspberrypi.com](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/):

> "To set up a user on first boot and bypass the wizard completely,
> create a file called userconf or userconf.txt in the boot partition of
> the SD card; [...] This file should contain a single line of text,
> consisting of username:encrypted- password – so your desired username,
> followed immediately by a colon, followed immediately by an encrypted
> representation of the password you want to use."

To generate the encrypted password, the easiest way is to use OpenSSL on a Raspberry Pi that is already running – open a terminal window and enter

```
echo 'mypassword' | openssl passwd -6 -stdin
```

If you don't have SSH access to the Raspberry, yet, you can of course also connect the microSD card with your PC, generate the encrypted password and place it in the boot partition.